# How to prove this trigonometrical inequality?

Tags: trigonometry

If $A=\sin ^8 \theta +\cos^{14} \theta $ then how to prove that for all values of $ \theta ,  0< A \le 1$?

Comment: $\sin^8 \theta \le \sin^2 \theta$, and similarly for $\cos$.

Answer (score 1):

According to @John, observe that, because the powers are even, $$\sin^8 \theta=|\sin^8 \theta| \le |\sin^2 \theta|=\sin^2 \theta \text{ and }\cos^{14} \theta = |\cos^{14} \theta| \le |\cos^2 \theta|=\cos^2 \theta.$$ These above inequalities result because $0 \le |\cos \theta| \le 1$ and $0 \le |\sin \theta| \le 1$. So we have \begin{align}A&=\sin^8 \theta+\cos^{14} \theta \\ &\le \sin^2 \theta+\cos^2 \theta \\ &=1.\end{align}
Also, when $|\sin \theta| = 0$, then $|\cos \theta| > 0$, and vice versa. This means $$A > 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate to find the maxima and the minima: The differential would be:

$$8\ sin^7x  \cos x-14 cos^{13} x \sin x$$

Equate it to zero: After solving it you will get the points of maxima as $n\pi/2$, where $n$ is any integer and the minima occurs whenever $\sin x = \frac 23$.

To get the minima you can also use the fact that arithmetic mean is greater than geometric mean. Thus what you'll get is:

$$ f(x)\ge \cos^3 x \sin^4 (2x)/8$$
Where $f(x)$ is the equation given to you. The maximum value that the product on the left hand side achieves is when $\sin(x) = 2/3$. This was again found by differentiation.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that
$$
0<\sin ^8 \theta +\cos^{14} \theta\le \sin ^2 \theta +\cos^2 \theta=1
$$
Because $\sin \theta $ and $\cos \theta$ are never both zero (because $\sin ^2 \theta +\cos^2 \theta=1$) and $|\sin \theta |\le 1$ and $|\cos \theta|\le1.$